# MongoDB using $cond with Update ($inc)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-update

Is there any way to use $cond along with ($set, $inc, ...) operators in update? (MongoDB 4.2) 
I want to update a field in my document by $inc it with "myDataInt" if a condition comes true, otherwise keeps it as it is:

```
db.mycoll.update(
    {"_id" : "5e9e5da03da783817d231dc4"},
    {"$inc" : {
       "my_data_sum" : {
           "$cond" : [
               {
                  "$ne" : ["snapshot_time", new_snapshot_time)]
               },myDataInt, 0]
           ]
       }
    },
    {upsert=True, multi=False}
)
```

However, this gives an error in pymongo:

```
raise WriteError(error.get("errmsg"), error.get("code"), error)
pymongo.errors.WriteError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$cond' in 'my_data_sum.$cond' is not valid for storage.
```

Any idea to avoid using find() before update in this case?

**Update:**

If I use the approach that Joe has mentioned, an exception will be raised in PyMongo (v3.10.1) due to using 'list' as a parameter in update_many() instead of 'dict':

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydb']

db.mycoll.update_many(
    {"_id" : "5e9e5da03da783817d231dc4"},
    [{"$set" : {
       "my_data_sum" : {
           "$sum": [
               "$my_data_sum",
               {"$cond" : [
                   {"$ne" : ["snapshot_time", new_snapshot_time]},
                   myDataInt, 
                   0
               ]}
           ]
       }
    }}],

    upsert:true
)
```

That ends up with this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1076, in update_many session=session),
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 856, in _update_retryable _update, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1491, in _retryable_write return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1384, in _retry_with_session return func(session, sock_info, retryable)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 852, in _update retryable_write=retryable_write)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 823, in _update _check_write_command_response(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 221, in _check_write_command_response _raise_last_write_error(write_errors)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 203, in _raise_last_write_error raise WriteError(error.get("errmsg"), error.get("code"), error)
pymongo.errors.WriteError: Modifiers operate on fields but we found type array instead. For example: {$mod: {<field>: ...}} not {$set: [ { $set: { my_data_sum: { $sum: [ "$my_data_sum", { $cond: [ { $ne: [ "$snapshot_time", 1586910283 ] }, 1073741824, 0 ] } ] } } } ]}
```

Comment: Please add a sample input document to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time and searching online, I figured that the `update_many()`, `update_one()`, and `update()` methods of Collection object in PyMongo do not accept type list as parameters to support the new Aggregation Pipeline feature of the Update operation in MongoDB 4.2+. (At least this option is not available in PyMongo v3.10 yet.)

However, looks like I could use the `command` method of the Database object in PyMongo which is an instance of the ([MongoDB runCommand](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/)) and it worked just fine for me:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydb']

result = db.command(
    {
        "update" : "mycoll",
        "updates" : [{
            "q" : {"_id" : "5e9e5da03da783817d231dc4"},
            "u" : [
                {"$set" : {
                   "my_data_sum" : {
                       "$sum": [
                           "$my_data_sum",
                           {"$cond" : [
                               {"$ne" : ["snapshot_time", new_snapshot_time]},
                               myDataInt,
                               0
                           ]}
                       ]
                   }
                }}
            ],
            "upsert" : True,
            "multi" : True
        }],
        "ordered": False
    }
)
```

The `command` method of the database object gets a dict object of all the required commands as its first argument, and then the list of Aggregation Pipeline can be included inside the dict object (`q` is the update query, and the `u` defined the fields to be updated).

`result` is a dictionary of Ack message from MongoDB which contains **'nModified'**, **'upserted'**, and **'writeErrors'**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MongoDB 4.2, you can use aggregation operators with updates.  `$inc` is not an aggregation operator, but `$sum` is.  To specify a pipeline, pass an array as the second argument to `update`:

```
db.coll.update(
    {"_id" : "5e9e5da03da783817d231dc4"},
    [{"$set" : {
       "my_data_sum" : {
           "$sum": [
               "$my_data_sum",
               {"$cond" : [
                   {"$ne" : ["snapshot_time", new_snapshot_time]},
                   myDataInt, 
                   0
               ]}
           ]
       }
    }}],
    {upsert:true, multi:false}
)
```

Comment: I was trying to do the same approach but looks like pymongo do not accept "list" as the second argument for both "update" and "update_many". It only accepts dict type! Any idea? (using pymongo 3.10)

Comment: According to the [docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many) `update_one` and `update_many` accept a pipeline starting with version 3.9.  What version of MongoDB are you running?

Comment: I'm running MongoDB 4.2 and PyMongo 3.10.1. I can run this Update in MongoDB with no problem. But PyMongo does not accept list type as the update_one or update_many parameters and gives this error:
`TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or any other type that inherits from collections.Mapping`

Comment: Can you edit the new python code into the question so we can try it out?

Answer (score 0):

https://mongoplayground.net/p/1AklFKuhFi6

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "like": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "like": 1
  }
]
```

let value = 1,

if you want to increment then use

**value = -1 * value**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "count": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $gt: [
              "$like",
              0
            ]
          },
          then: {
            "$subtract": [
              "$like",
               value
            ]
          },
          else: 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```